# Dataframe object not callable while calculating moving averages of time series data

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tickers=['XOM', 'NVDA', 'ML.PA','AAPL','WMT']#created ticker variable containing tickers for 5 company
df=pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start=startdate, end=enddate)['Adj Close']#got data from yahoo of just the adj close of these companies.
df.head()

dfflat=df.unstack().reset_index() # unstack the dataframe
dfflat.head()

dfflat.columns=['Ticker','Date','Close']


aapl=dfflat[dfflat['Ticker']=="AAPL"]
windows=[10,20,30]
for period in windows:
    column_name='MA for %s in days'%(str(period))
    aapl[column_name]=aapl('Close').rolling(period).mean()
aapl.head()
```

Extracted data to create dataframe for stock prices from yahoo using stock tickers, for the close column, trying to calculate the moving average using a for loop.
shows the following error

File "", line 5, in 
aapl[column_name]=aapl('Close').rolling(period).mean()

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
aapl[column_name]=aapl('Close').rolling(period).mean()
```

Change `aapl('Close')` to `aapl['Close']`:

```py
aapl[column_name]=aapl['Close'].rolling(period).mean()
```